# Ticket does not match the supplied service error using Grails, CAS, and LDAP

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap, cas

I have an app with Grails 2.2.3 that uses the plugins Spring Security Core 1.2.7.3, Spring Security CAS 1.0.5, and Spring Security LDAP 1.0.6.

I am using LDAP for roles, user storage and user info, and CAS for single sign on. When I authenticate the first time I get a `BadCredentials` exception (the one that says "not able to find a user with that username and password."), but if I try the second time it authenticates correctly.

When I debug that exception, it is actually caused by the error:

```
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: 
    ticket 'my-ticket' does not match supplied service
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error or how to fix it? Here are the settings in resources.groovy:

```
initialDirContextFactory(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource, "ldap://ldap.company.com:389") {
    userDn = "CN=Admin,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com"
    password = "password"
}

ldapUserSearch(FilterBasedLdapUserSearch,
               "OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com",
               "employeeId={0}",
               initialDirContextFactory) { }

ldapUserDetailsMapper(MyLdapUserDetailsContextMapper) { }

ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator,
                         initialDirContextFactory,
                         "ou=Groups,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com") {
    groupRoleAttribute = "cn"
    groupSearchFilter = "member={0}"
    rolePrefix = ""
    searchSubtree = true
    convertToUpperCase = true
    ignorePartialResultException = true
}

userDetailsService(LdapUserDetailsService, ldapUserSearch, ldapAuthoritiesPopulator) {
    userDetailsMapper = ref('ldapUserDetailsMapper')
}
```

And my settings in config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serverUrlPrefix = 'https://cas.company.com/cas'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.loginUri = "/login"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.cas.serviceUrl = "${grails.serverURL}/j_spring_cas_security_check"

grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['casAuthenticationProvider']

grails.plugins.springsecurity.defaultTargetUrl = '/'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.alwaysUseDefault = false
```